# Is it near real time, near real-time, near-real time, or near-real-time?

Tags: prefixes

> Your energy usage will be available in

- near real time
- near-real time
- near real-time
- near-real-time

> on your mobile.

Which is/are correct?

[[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=near-real-time%2Cnear-real%20time%2Cnear%20real-time%2C%20near%20real%20time&year_start=1950&year_end=2018)]

Answer (score 4):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing#Near_real-time) seems to suggest the third option is correct, *near real-time*.

While hyphenation is often arbitrary, I would suggest to follow the established usage in this case.

Having said that, in the same paragraph it also uses *near-real-time*:

> *...a near-real-time display depicts...*

Here *near real-time* is used as a modifier of *display*, so the hyphenation clarifies that it is one unit, rather than, say, a *near-real **time display***

Comment: That difference would be because the "_near real-time_" case is correct where it is used as a noun phrase, which is what the question was asking about. If you use it as a compound adjective, however, as in "_a near-real-time display_", then it's a triple-hyphenated-word. Er, I mean, a triple-hyphenated word.